# python3 dataframe - how to ignore nan ,0 and load specific column data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have following sample json file

```
{"id": 103, "data": [{"point": [10, 20], "sp": 2}, {"point": [20, 20], "sp": 3}, {"point": [10, 20], "sp": 0}, {"point": [30, 20], "sp": 0}]}
```

I read the json with json.load function and then perform

```
df = pd.DataFrame(filejson['data'])
```

if I print this df the data is shown as below using head() function

```
     Point  sp
0   [10, 20]   2
1   [20,20]  3
```

I would like to filter all null,zero from field "sp" so expecting output as

```
   sp
0   2
1   3
```

I would like to load only column "sp" and ignore all zero. is that possible?

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *list comprehension* here.

```
pd.DataFrame({'sp':[d.get('sp') for d in filejson['data'] if d.get('sp')]})

   sp
0   2
1   3
```

You can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) here.

```
pd.DataFrame({'sp': [*filter(None, map(itemgetter('sp'),filejson['data']))]})

   sp
0   2
1   3
```

Note:

> `filter(None, ...)` removes all [*`falsy`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/12416453) values i.e `False`, `0`, `''`, `[]` etc.

Comment: can I read the json to numpy array and get all speed data point in that?

Comment: @user269867 Not *NumPy expert* but AFAIK I don't think there's a function for it. Might be worth asking this as a new question. Might get an answer from NumPy experts. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
filejson={"id": 103, "data": [{"point": [10, 20], "sp": 2}, {"point": [20, 20], "sp": 3}, {"point": [10, 20], "sp": 0}, {"point": [30, 20], "sp": 0}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(filejson['data'])

df = df.replace(0,np.nan)
df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
df = pd.DataFrame(filejson['data'])[['sp']]
df = df.replace(np.nan, 0)
df = df.loc[~(df.sp == 0), :]
```

Comment: I like the idea to read from dataFrame directly instead of filtering but just curious , df.loc[~(df.sp == 0), :] --- what is this doing?

Comment: That checks `sp` for values which are nonzero and filters the dataframe for those values